# Is it possible? I see some strange behavior on a Fb page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I see a strange behavior on a fb page which the post date doesn't match the creation date and I am not sure is it possible using the FB api

[fb post date doesn't match the creation date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4mmq.jpg)

I tried to back date a post on a page and schedule a post on the same page, FB will only showed me the scheduled date (or the backdate) and time of the post.